# What's the name of this tree?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I photographed this flower on the street in Los Angeles.
[image]It looks like a lilac, but I am not sure.

Comment: It is not lilac. which part of earth do you see this? [Crepe Mrtyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagerstroemia) perhaps - I passed by some.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably a crape myrtle, a plant from the Genus [*Lagerstroemia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagerstroemia).

Here is another photo for comparison:

[image]

And here another photo, showing the whole tree:

[image]

Comment: I doublechecked on the internet. You are right!